# Parámetros de URL

Tags: url

¿Cómo puedo obtener los parámetros de una url y presentarlos en la página hecha en google sites?.
Por ejemplo, tengo la siguiente url en el navegador:

https://sites.google.com/view/anaems/inicio?nombre=Luis&apellido=Tello&salon=4

en la pagina **inicio** hecha con google sites, deseo mostrar:
Nombre : Luis

Apellido : Tello

Salon : 4

Comment: Para eso tendrás que usar JavaScript o algún lenguaje que interactúe con el navegador como PHP. Estos no están disponibles en Google Site ni en ningún otro CMS o creador de sitios, así que tendrás que crear tu propio sitio desde cero usando HTML, CSS & JavaScript. Además, deberás contratar un alojamiento (hosting) para que tu sitio web sea accesible desde internet, finalmente, un certificado SSL para asegurar tu sitio web.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Una duda más:  Podría realizarlo mediante un gadgets?

Answer (score 0):

**No es posible**

Antes, con la versión clásica era posible pero desde la última actualización el 2023 ya no lo es.

Por ejemplo, podrías insertar javascript desde el botón `incorporar` y colocar el siguiente código:

```
<script>
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.top.location.search);
    for (let [key, value] of urlParams) {
       console.log(key,value)
    }
</script>
```

El problema, es que cada panel genera uno o más `iframe` anidados. Y esos iframes tienen dominios distintos. Esto es fácilmente verificable si hacemos un `window.location.ancestorOrigins`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y por supuesto al ser dominios distintos salta el infame error de CORS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En conclusión, es posible ingresar código javascript que solo interactúe con el panel incrustado, no con la página completa, haciendo imposible realizar lo que tu requieres.

Esta nueva versión tampoco tiene gadgets, por lo que tampoco es posible ir por ese camino

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por sus comentaros. Me quedó muy claro.